# IIS hosting an ASP Core API

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, asp.net-core, windows-server-2012-r2

Got the following issue with a Web API I've been working on, my issue lies within how am I supposed to configure the Web API to work with IIS (Windows Server 2012 R2) considering the fact that I've been following this document's [directions](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html) and I still get 'This page can't be displayed' browser error :

The Windows Server is hosted on Azure.

I've even added this part related to IIS authentication (thought that this may not cause my issue), adding/removing it has no effect whatsoever.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddOptions();

        services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardWindowsAuthentication = false;
        });
     }
```

As in how I've created my `publish` folder I've proceeded as following :

```
dotnet publish
```

This caused the following folder structure

- refs
- runtimes
- lots of .dll's (references to various assemblies such as aspnetcore.mvc, httpclient,etc)
- web.config
- mywebAPI.deps (json file with dependencies)
- mywebAPI.dll
- mywebAPI.pdb
- appsettings.JSON

According to the [directory structure](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/hosting/directory-structure.html) I do miss wwwroot and Views because I have them implicitly mentioned in my `project.json`, but I don't need them since I have a web api and not a web form app.

```
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  }
```

Configuring steps on IIS
Created a folder on the main drive where I've placed the result of the publish.
Went to IIS Manager and added a new website
Went to application pool and set the .NET CLR Version to 'No Managed Code'

[image]

Launching the app throws me right into this browser error - This page can’t be displayed

Running from CMD dotnet mywebapi.dll WORKS... and I've tested it with Postman (have postman on the Windows Server).

[image]

Comment: Turn on FREB and examine the logs. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/docast/2016/04/28/troubleshooting-iis-request-performance-slowness-issues-using-freb-tracing/

Comment: Can you post the contents of your web.config file? There might probably be an IIS config issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more information.

**Enable and check the application logs** at `.\logs\stdout`.

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add 
         name="aspNetCore" 
         path="*" 
         verb="*" 
         modules="AspNetCoreModule" 
         resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore 
         processPath=".\MyApp.exe" 
         arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" 
         stdoutLogEnabled="false"                  <--- enable
         stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />          <--- set path
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Check the IIS logs** (you probably do NOT have to enable them first). Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application. To drill down, you can Filter Current Log... by Event level et cetera.

[image: IIS Application Logs]

Comment: Hey,
I've managed to fix it.... in my launchSettings.json I had this launchUrl : http://localhost:5000/../...

In IIS I chose a wrong host name for the api (instead of localhost I was writing off something custom of mine)

Apparently what I write (as host) in the launchSettings.json needs to be (OBVIOUS...) chosen as a hostname binding in IIS...

I'll post an update/answer asap.